# How do I troubleshoot booting into black screen?

Tags: 10.04, boot, pxe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I installed Lucid Lynx over PXE onto this dell server seemingly successfully, but booting from the HD results in a black, unpowered screen.  There appears to be no network connectivity to the box either.  It may have landed at a textual busybox type prompt, but I can't see it.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Delete</kbd> seems to reboot.

On my last attempt I held shift and the grub menu came up, but recovery mode produced the same results.

Should I drop into the grub prompt and give the kernel a magical boot option?  Should I boot from a rescue cd and munge some bits on the HD?  Give up and install windows?

Comment: Have you removed the `quiet` option from grubs kernel commandline? If not, try to boot without `quiet` and `splash`. You'll see some output.

Comment: Could you change your subject to something like 'Lucid Lynx ..'. When I read lynx I'm thinking of the application `lynx` and not Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: I think of the animal from my 5th grad animal report!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a couple of "magical boot options" to try:

- `nomodeset`
- `i915.modeset=0 xforcevesa`

I'd remove `quiet splash` when trying these and only one at a time, not together as they'll likely conflict.

---

Edit: for an explanation of *how* to use these:

- When booting, hold left-<kbd>Shift</kbd>
- Highlight the first option and press <kbd>e</kbd>
- Go down to the line that looks like:

  ```
  /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.blah-generic root=UUID=blah ro quiet splash
  ```
- Replace `quite splash` with your boot option of choice.

If that works out well, you can make the changes to `/etc/default/grub` by editing the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` value. After saving, run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: thank you for your options.  before I saw your answer I used the ubuntu pxe rescue to install nvidia-latest, which eventually resolved my issue.  Dell Precision T3500

Answer (score 0):

It is likely to be related to plymouth/mountall check the following blog entry for some tips:
http://handypenguin.blogspot.com/2010/04/when-recovery-mode-fails-to-boot.html